# SELECT from subquery in Codeigniter Active Record

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How would I do the following query in Codeigniter ActiveRecord : -

```
SELECT *, 

(SELECT 
        image_path
    FROM
        image
    WHERE
        image_table = 'model'
            AND image_table_id = model_id
    GROUP BY image_table_id
    LIMIT 1) AS ModelImg 

FROM

   (SELECT 
      *
   FROM
      vw_newcars
    where offer_table = 'derivative'
    order by offer_order
   ) x

WHERE make_name = 'Fiat'
group by offer_table_id
limit 12
```

The part I'm having problems with is how to do a select from subquery in Active Record.

I don't see a `from_select` function or anything comparable in the documentation.

Comment: What version codeigniter you used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to get the query to work by putting the `from` sub_query into the initial select statement :

```
$this->db->select("*, 
  (select image_path from image where image_table = 'model' and image_table_id = model_id
  group by image_table_id limit 1) as ModelImg FROM 
  (SELECT * FROM $view where offer_table = 'derivative' order by offer_order) x");
```

Comment: I prefer $this->query($sql); to run the complete query at once

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->select('(SELECT image_path FROM image WHERE image_table = "model" AND image_table_id = model_id GROUP BY image_table_id LIMIT 1) AS ModelImg');
$this->db->from('(SELECT * FROM vw_newcars WHERE offer_table = "derivative" ORDER BY offer_order) x');
$this->db->where('make_name', 'Fiat');
$this->db->group_by('offer_table_id');
$this->db->limit(12);

$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result();
```