# Retrieve single row as a query result for an EAV model in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, entity-attribute-value

I have implemented an EAV model using MySQL (phpmyadmin) for an e-commerce website developed with CodeIgniter Framework (PHP).
The EAV Model goes this way:

**Table**: *Products*

```
id | name   | description
-------------------------
1  | prod_1 | lorem
2  | prod_2 | ipsum
```

**Table**: *Attributes*

```
id | name   | description
-------------------------
1  | attr_1 | dolor
2  | attr_2 | sit
3  | attr_3 | amet
```

**Table**: *Product_Attributes*

```
id | prod_id | attr_id
-------------------------
1  | 1       | 1
2  | 1       | 2
3  | 2       | 1
4  | 2       | 2
5  | 2       | 3
```

I have generated a result using multiple joins, which looks as follows:

```
product_name | attribute_name | product_description
---------------------------------------------------
prod_1       | attr_1         | lorem
prod_1       | attr_2         | lorem
prod_2       | attr_1         | ipsum
prod_2       | attr_2         | ipsum
prod_2       | attr_3         | ipsum
```

The query used for above result is as follows:

```php
function getProductList() {
  return $this->db->select('p.name as product_name, a.name as attribute_name, p.description as product_description')
                  ->from('products as p')
                  ->join('product_attributes as pa', 'pa.prod_id = p.id', 'LEFT')
                  ->join('attributes as a', 'a.id = pa.attr_id', 'LEFT')
                  ->get();
}
```

But, what I want as a result of the query is as follows:

```
product_name | attribute_name           | product_description
-------------------------------------------------------------
prod_1       | (attr_1, attr_2)         | lorem
prod_2       | (attr_1, attr_2, attr_3) | ipsum
```

The drawback of the current query result is that I have to perform a nested loop on the result to display a list of products and their attributes, which affects the performance. I'm open for any suggestion(s) to improve the performance of the query or its result.

**--EDIT--**

I also have other tables linked with the `Products` table. Say, for example, there's an additional table as follows:

**Table**: *Dimensions*

```
id | name   | value
-----------------
1  | length | 20
2  | breadth| 15
3  | height | 20
```

**Table**: *Product_Dimensions*

```
id | prod_id | dim_id
-------------------------
1  | 1       | 1
2  | 1       | 2
3  | 1       | 3
4  | 2       | 1
5  | 2       | 2
```

Thus, the expected output modified as follows:

```
product_name | attribute_name           | product_description| dimension_name            | dimension_value
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
prod_1       | (attr_1, attr_2)         | lorem              | (length, breadth, height) | (20, 15, 20)*
prod_2       | (attr_1, attr_2, attr_3) | ipsum              | (length, breadth)         | (20, 15)
```

But, the obtained output is as follows:

```
product_name | attribute_name                                   | product_description| dimension_name                                      | dimension_value
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
prod_1       | (attr_1, attr_2, attr_1, attr_2, attr_1, attr_2) | lorem              | (length, breadth, height, length, breadth, height)  | (20, 15, 20, 20, 15, 20)
prod_2       | (attr_1, attr_2, attr_3, attr_1, attr_2, attr_3) | ipsum              | (length, breadth, length, breadth, length, breadth) | (20, 15, 20, 15, 20, 15)
```

**--EDIT--**

When used `DISTINCT` under `GROUP_BY`, the output gets modified as follows:

```
product_name | attribute_name           | product_description| dimension_name            | dimension_value
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
prod_1       | (attr_1, attr_2)         | lorem              | (length, breadth, height) | (20, 15)*
prod_2       | (attr_1, attr_2, attr_3) | ipsum              | (length, breadth)         | (20, 15)
```

***You can see the difference between the expected and obtained output. The intended duplicates also get erased by using `DISTINCT`.**

*SQL Fiddle* to try your hands on [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/da3d9/2).

Comment: Your concern is running the loop in PHP? Have you measured its performance impact? I would be surprised if it was significant or even measureable, as in any code talking to the database, the query's execute time is likely to be far longer than the application code's. SQL produces 2 dimensional results and it is normal practice to reformat them into more dimensions in display logic, and unless you have a demonstrable performance problem you've isolated to the loop, I would suggest what you have already is fine and correct.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Thanks, for your share of knowledge. But, I wonder if there's a better way to query the result. Because, the example that I have illustrated includes join of mere 3  tables with limited attributes but, the database I'm dealing with requires multiple such joins with each product having at least 20 attributes (which may increase further). Thus, if I have to display a list of say 10k+ products, the query result may include 2lakhs+ rows, which is the number of loop iterations.

Comment: That is a large loop indeed. The examples suggested below using GROUP_CONCAT() will reformat the query but will probably still require a loop in your view. They will have an impact on query performance, possible equal to just using the loop over 2D results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just execute three simple queries. Get products. Get attributes. Get dimensions.
Then map attributes and dimensions to corresponding products.
This is how probably any ORM is performing eager loading.

I'm not familiar with codeigniter, but I think it should look something like this:

```
$query = $this->db->get('products');

$products = [];
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
    // init empty arrays for attributes & dimensions
    $row->attributes = [];
    $row->dimensions = [];
    // should be indexed by id, so we can find id later to map attributes & dimensions
    $products[$row->id] = $row;
}

$attributes = $this->db
    ->select('pa.product_id, a.name')
    ->from('product_attributes as pa')
    ->join('attributes as a', 'a.id = pa.attribute_id')
    ->get();

$dimensions = $this->db
    ->select('pd.product_id, d.name, d.value')
    ->from('product_dimensions as pd')
    ->join('dimensions as d', 'd.id = pd.dimension_id')
    ->get();

foreach ($attributes as $attr) {
    $products[$attr->product_id]->attributes[] = $attr->name;
}

foreach ($dimensions as $dim) {
    $products[$dim->product_id]->dimensions[] = $dim;
    unset($dim->product_id);
}
```

Now you get all your data in a nicely nested structure. With `echo json_encode($products, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)` you would get:

```
{
    "1": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Product_1",
        "description": "Lorem",
        "attributes": [
            "Attribute_1",
            "Attribute_2"
        ],
        "dimensions": [
            {
                "name": "length",
                "value": "15"
            },
            {
                "name": "breadth",
                "value": "25"
            },
            {
                "name": "height",
                "value": "15"
            }
        ]
    },
    "2": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Product_2",
        "description": "Ipsum",
        "attributes": [
            "Attribute_1",
            "Attribute_2",
            "Attribute_3"
        ],
        "dimensions": [
            {
                "name": "length",
                "value": "15"
            },
            {
                "name": "breadth",
                "value": "25"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

You can traverse it in the view layer or your export code, and output in any way you need.

#### Update

In MySQL 5.7+ you can get the same result as a single JSON string with a single query:

```
select json_arrayagg(json_object(
  'id', p.id,
  'name', p.name,
  'description', p.description,
  'attributes', (
    select json_arrayagg(a.name)
    from product_attributes pa
    join attributes a on a.id = pa.attribute_id
    where pa.product_id = p.id
  ),
  'dimensions', ( 
    select json_arrayagg(json_object(
      'name',  d.name,
      'value', d.value
    ))
    from product_dimensions pd
    join dimensions d on d.id = pd.dimension_id
    where pd.product_id = p.id
  )
))
from products p;
```

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jShoLkGEGqMUjGrDd6TzfL/0)

Or maybe you want something "simple" like this:

```
select p.*, (
    select group_concat(a.name order by a.id separator ', ')
    from product_attributes pa
    join attributes a on a.id = pa.attribute_id
    where pa.product_id = p.id
  ) as attributes, (
    select group_concat(d.name, ': ', d.value order by d.id separator ', ')
    from product_dimensions pd
    join dimensions d on d.id = pd.dimension_id
    where pd.product_id = p.id
  ) as dimensions
from products p;
```

which will return:

```
| id  | name      | description | attributes                            | dimensions                          |
| --- | --------- | ----------- | ------------------------------------- | ----------------------------------- |
| 1   | Product_1 | Lorem       | Attribute_1, Attribute_2              | length: 15, breadth: 25, height: 15 |
| 2   | Product_2 | Ipsum       | Attribute_1, Attribute_2, Attribute_3 | length: 15, breadth: 25             |
```

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kzwhFGKeQKzb6CPx668rfn/0)

But if you need the result exactly as in the question, then you can try this one:

```
select 
  p.name as product_name,
  (
    select concat('(', group_concat(a.name order by a.id separator ', '), ')')
    from product_attributes pa
    join attributes a on a.id = pa.attribute_id
    where pa.product_id = p.id
  ) as attribute_name,
  concat('(', group_concat(d.name order by d.id separator ', '), ')') as dimension_name,
  concat('(', group_concat(d.value order by d.id separator ', '), ')') as dimension_value,
  p.description as product_description
from products p
left join product_dimensions pd on pd.product_id = p.id
left join dimensions d on d.id = pd.dimension_id
group by p.id;
```

Result:

```
| product_name | product_description | attribute_name                          | dimension_name            | dimension_value |
| ------------ | ------------------- | --------------------------------------- | ------------------------- | --------------- |
| Product_1    | Lorem               | (Attribute_1, Attribute_2)              | (length, breadth, height) | (15, 25, 15)    |
| Product_2    | Ipsum               | (Attribute_1, Attribute_2, Attribute_3) | (length, breadth)         | (15, 25)        |
```

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tnmiB8wb96vsM3kWrnF8LD/0)

Comment: Seems good, except that you have interchanged the `from` and `where` clause of *attributes* and *dimensions*. :P
Also, I was inquisitive, if there's a `SQL` way of doing this?

Comment: Hmm.. Strange. I have no idea how that could have hapened :-)

Comment: @RahulSoni Note that SQL queries always return tables. You cannot return a nested structure. You thogh can return a JSON string with MYSQL 5.7.

Comment: Thanks, for that! Though, your answer has some syntactical errors, I can't point out all. Please do rectify them.

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to reach your expected value, you have to use [`GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html). For CodeIgniter you find it here, you find it [Guide page](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html) in this part `$this->db->group_by()`.

```
function getProductList() {
  return $this->db->select('p.name as product_name, concat(\'( \', GROUP_CONCAT(a.name), \' )\') as attribute_name, p.description as product_description')
                  ->from('products as p')
                  ->join('product_attributes as pa', 'pa.prod_id = p.id', 'LEFT')
                  ->join('attributes as a', 'a.id = pa.attr_id', 'LEFT')
                  ->group_by(array('p.name', 'p.description'))
                  ->get();
}
```

As you see here, `grouping by` the columns name i wish to print, and `concat` the column name you wish to retrieve. Hope this helps, Good luck.

**EDITED**

If you want to use concat or any of aggregation functions on more than one column, you have to do it as `GROUP_CONCAT(a.name)` as show below.

```
function getProductList() {
      return $this->db->select('p.name as product_name, 
                GROUP_CONCAT(a.name) as attribute_name, 
                GROUP_CONCAT(a.name) as attribute_name_2, 
                GROUP_CONCAT(a.name) as attribute_name_3, 
                p.description as product_description')
                  ->...
                  ->group_by(array('p.name', 'p.description'))
                  ->get();
}
```

Be aware, if you want to `concat` a column, you have not set it with `group by` statement.

[These examples](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) will give you a good idea about it, Good luck.

**EDITED**

This should work.

```
function getProductList() {
      return $this->db->select('p.name as product_name, 
                GROUP_CONCAT(a.name) as attribute_name, 
                p.description as product_description, 
                GROUP_CONCAT(d.name) as dimension_name, 
                GROUP_CONCAT(d.value) as dimension_value')
                  ->...
                  ->group_by(array('p.name', 'p.description'))
                  ->get();
}
```

**EDITED**

You could use `distinct` inside the `group_concat` so it gives a uniq data as you wish.

```
function getProductList() {
      return $this->db->select('p.name as product_name, 
                GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a.name) as attribute_name, 
                p.description as product_description, 
                GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT d.name) as dimension_name, 
                GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT d.value) as dimension_value')
                  ->...
                  ->group_by(array('p.name', 'p.description'))
                  ->get();
}
```

**EDITED**

As i told you in the comments sections, you have to use subquery if you wish to do what you want, And this is how you can do it.

```
function getProductList() {
  return $this->db->select('pname, pdesc, aname, adesc, group_concat(dname), group_concat(dvalue)')
                  ->from('( select
                        p.name as pname,
                        p.description as pdesc,
                        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a.name) as aname,
                        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a.description) as adesc,
                        d.name as dname, 
                        d.value as dvalue

                        from products as p
                        left join product_attributes as pa on pa.product_id = p.id
                        left join attributes as a on a.id = pa.attribute_id
                        left join product_dimensions as pd on pd.product_id = p.id
                        left join dimensions as d on d.id = pd.dimension_id

                        group by p.id, p.description, d.name) as d' )
                  ->group_by(array('pname', 'pdesc', 'aname', 'adesc'))
                  ->get();
}
```

[sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/da3d9/69)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But, you have concatenated `(` `)` (round braces) as well, any reason behind that?

Comment: You're welcome, that because in your expected output you have it like this. Its look like that the code is working for you, you can just edit it as you wish. Good luck.

Comment: The answer you provided works well, if there's a single column concat. Can you help me with concat for multiple columns?

Comment: Yes, you do the same for the other columns, `GROUP_CONCAT(a.name), GROUP_CONCAT(a.name), GROUP_CONCAT(a.name), GROUP_CONCAT(a.name)` but make sure that if you want to do concat for a column, you have not to set it in the `group by` statement, Good luck.

Comment: Can you kindly modify your answer as per the *edit*?

Comment: The edited answer doesn't work for my edited question. : (

Comment: @RahulSoni And what's exactly that doesn't work? is there any problem?

Comment: There are duplicate entries after `group_concat` and when I used `distinct` to avoid duplicates, the intended/required duplicates, too, get filtered out. Also, `group_concat` for multiple cols. works fine in a normal SQL query but, gives a syntax error for the query developed using CI helpers.

Comment: @RahulSoni Is the problem still or you have solve it? and if it is still same, update your answer with the exact problem, so we can help you again. Good luck.

Comment: No, using `DISTINCT` doesn't help. :( 
Kindly refer the updated question.

Comment: @RahulSoni Kindly, Update your SQL Fiddle URL.

Comment: Updated. Thanks for bringing to my notice. :)

Comment: @RahulSoni I'm not sure if you can reach what you want with a simple `group by ` statement, you may need to use sub query to do it. Good luck.

Comment: @RahulSoni i have updated my answer, check it. if doesnt work with you using subquery in from CI function, use it in select statement with from word as pointed out in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/29920022, Good luck.

Comment: @RahulSoni have you tried the answer or there is something wrong? give us more detail so we can help you.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts but, @PaulSpiegel 's answer was much more helpful involving ORM. As his answer contains some syntactical errors, I have awarded the bounty to your answer which complies with my conditions.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the MySQL function [GROUP_CONCAT](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group_concat/) to get the desired result :

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c51040/3

Comment: Thanks Alex, for your contribution! :)
Your answer would have been more helpful if, it would have resembled CodeIgniter querying structure.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do it lile this

```
function getProductList() {
  return $this->db->select('p.name as product_name
                     , GROUP_CONCAT(a.name SEPARATOR ",") as attribute_name
                     , min(p.description) as product_description')
                  ->from('products as p')
                  ->join('product_attributes as pa', 'pa.prod_id = p.id', 'LEFT')
                  ->join('attributes as a', 'a.id = pa.attr_id', 'LEFT')
                  ->group_by("p.name");
                  ->get();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But, is there any specific reason for the `min()` used for `product_description`?

Comment: my server has full_group, probably it will function without it, but every displayed column should, be either in the group_by or have an aggregation function.

Answer (score 0):

Try This using Sub Query.
Codeigniter Code :

```
$this->db->select("select p.name as pname, p.description as pdesc, t2.aname, t2.adesc,t3.dname,t3.dvalue");
$this->db->from("products p");
$this->db->join("(select pa.product_id,GROUP_CONCAT(a.name) as aname, GROUP_CONCAT(a.description) as adesc from  product_attributes as pa 
left join attributes as a on a.id = pa.attribute_id
group by pa.product_id) t2","t2.product_id=p.id","left");
$this->db->join("(select group_concat(name) as dname,group_concat(value) as dvalue,pd.product_id from product_dimensions pd
left join dimensions d on d.id = pd.dimension_id
group by pd.product_id) t3","t3 on t3.product_id = p.id","left");
$this->db->group_by("p.id");
$this->db->get()->result_array();
```

MySql Query :

```
select p.name as pname, p.description as pdesc, t2.aname, t2.adesc,t3.dname,t3.dvalue
from products as p
left join (select pa.product_id,GROUP_CONCAT(a.name) as aname, GROUP_CONCAT(a.description) as adesc from  product_attributes as pa 
left join attributes as a on a.id = pa.attribute_id
group by pa.product_id) t2 on t2.product_id=p.id
left join
(select group_concat(name) as dname,group_concat(value) as dvalue,pd.product_id from product_dimensions pd
left join dimensions d on d.id = pd.dimension_id
group by pd.product_id) t3 on t3.product_id = p.id
group by p.id
```

[Click here to see result](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/da3d9/40/0)